# Routing for ElectronJS26 with React HashRouter, built routes do not work

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite

In my electron app, i try to open two browserwindows, a simple page on the first, and a video on the second.

To make this project, i created the app through electron-vite, with typescript and react.

The second window gives me this error, once i run the built deb file on my system:

```
(node:15251) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///opt/alapko-electron/resources/app.asar/renderer/index.html/videos/0 with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This is my router:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
        <Route path="/video/:id" element={<VideoComponent/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

and within my index.ts file, this is how i try to load the window:

```js
 videoWindow.loadFile(path.join(app.getAppPath(), "/renderer/index.html" + "/videos/0"))
```

How would i have to change the loadFile parameters so it would work in production?

I tried it so far with Hashrouter, doing that the route was messed, electron changed the # into something else, but it looked like this:

```js
 videoWindow.loadFile(path.join(app.getAppPath(), "/renderer/index.html" + "#/video/0"))
```

edit:

```js
    if (is.dev && process.env["ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL"]) 
{
videoWindow.loadURL(process.env["ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL"] + "/video/0")
}
```

this works great when i run dev.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `"#/videos/0"` from `path.join()`?